# how to replace pattern in multi-line in linux

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, sed, awk

Assume I have a file called text.txt
In text.txt, I have a number of the following pattern:

```
/**
 * @something
**/
```

I want to replace this pattern to empty string. What is the easiest Linux command to do this?

1. "grep" does not work because this is multi line pattern.
2. I tried "sed", but I cannot get it worked.
3. I guess "awk" may be easy for that, but "awk" seems so complicated and I am not familiar with "awk".

Comment: sed should never be attempted for any multi-line problem, it is strictly for substitutions on a single line. awk is not complicated, it just requires a small paradigm shift to use it because it provides by default much of the functionality that you'd have to write by hand in other tools/languages for parsing text files (e.g. reading lines, splitting into fields, etc.) but once you've used it a couple of times it's not more complicated than any other Algol-based language.

Comment: You're getting answers based on several different interpretations of your requirements. You stand the best chance of getting a robust answer if you provide a truly representative input file (i.e. one containing at least 2 of the patterns you want removed) and the associated expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that our input file is:

```
$ cat text.txt
before
/**
 * @something
**/
after
```

We can filter out the comments with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/\/\*\*/ {c=1; next} /\*\*\// {c=0; next} c==0 {print}' text.txt
before
after
```

The `awk` works by having a variable as a flag called `c`.  When we start, `c=0` signaling that we are not in a comment.  When the start-of-comment line appears, `/**`, we set `c=1`.  `c` stays at one until the next end-of-comment line, `**/`, appears in which case `c` is set back to 0.  The line is only printed out if `c=0`.  Anything, whatever the format, between the open and close comment lines is not printed.

The code is a funny looking because both `/` and `*` are active characters to `awk`.  So, they both need to be escaped with backlashes.  Thus, for example, the regular expression to look for the start-of-comment line looks like `\/\*\*` while the regular expression for end-of-comment looks like `\*\*\/`.

#### More complex input files

Suppose the input file has a more complex structure such as illustrated in JS's example:

```
$ cat file
something
/**
 * @something
**/ random
hello
hi /**
 * @something
**/ bye
hola
gracias
bye
```

We can handle this with `awk` as follows:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\*\\*/\n*' '{sub(/\n*\/\*\*.*/,"",$0); print $0}' file
something
 random
hello
hi 
 bye
hola
gracias
bye
```

The above was tested with GNU `awk`.  Since it uses a multi-character record separator, it may not work with older versions of `awk`.

While `awk` normally reads a file line by line, in our version above we have set the record separator, `RS`, to match the end of a comment.  Then, we delete everything from the comment start to the end of the record and print the record.

Comment: You can simplify this by changing the order of it. You do then not need the  `next` statement.  See my post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk` to remove the text from, to a given pattern:

```
cat file
before
/**
 * @something
**/
after
```

```
awk '/\*\*\//{f=0} f; /\/\*\*/{f=1}' file
 * @something
```

When you do not like to include START/END pattern, this is one of the most simple `awk` to handle this:

```
awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS to read the whole file as one string:

If you specifically want to remove just the string you posted, that'd be:

```
$ cat file
foo/**
 * @something
**/bar and more/**
 * @something
**/stuff

$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -v pat='/**
 * @something
**/' '{
    while ( s=index($0,pat) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+length(pat))
    }
    print
}' file
foobar and morestuff
```

or if you actually just want to remove everything between each occurrence of `/**` and `/` all you need is:

```
awk -v RS='/[*][*][^/]+/' -v ORS= '1' file
foobar and morestuff
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat text.txt | egrep -v "[/]" | egrep -v "[*] @" > newtext.txt
```

would do it, but you may have to modify slightly depending on what else is in the file.

Comment: UUOC and would require much more than slight modification to become a robust solution